# Seaborn plot does not update when chaning a select widget inside a Panel dasboard

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, panel, dashboard

I try to build a Panel Dashboard with a seaborne plot. The code works and showing the widgets and the plot, but when I select a different year or month, the plot does not update. What am I doing wrong?

```
import xarray as xr
import seaborn as sns
import panel as pn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import pandas as pd
pn.extension()

x = [numpy.datetime64('2011-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-02T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-04T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-05T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-06T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-07T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-08T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-10T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-11T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-12T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-13T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-14T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-15T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-16T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-17T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-18T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-19T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-20T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-21T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-22T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-23T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-24T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-25T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-26T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-27T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-28T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-29T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-30T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-01-31T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-02T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-04T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-05T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-06T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-07T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-08T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-09T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-10T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-11T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-12T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-13T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-14T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-15T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-16T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-17T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-18T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-19T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-20T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-21T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-22T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-23T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-24T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-25T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-26T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-27T00:00:00.000000000'),
  numpy.datetime64('2011-02-28T00:00:00.000000000'),  numpy.datetime64('2011-03-01T00:00:00.000000000')]
y =  [0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  3.0,  2.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  6.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  3.0,  1.0,
  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0]

data = pd.DataFrame({'time':x, 'value':y})
month_options = {'Januar' : 1, 'Februar' : 2}
month = pn.widgets.Select(name='Monat', options = month_options, value=1)
@pn.depends(month)
def dashboard(month):
    subset = data[data.time.dt.month == month] 
    def frosteindringtiefe(ds):
        sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
        bar = sns.barplot(x=ds.time, y=ds.value)
        ax.set_xticklabels(labels=range(len(ds.time)))
        plt.title(list(month_options.keys())[month -1 ])
        plt.ylabel('Frosteindringtiefe in cm')
        
        return bar    
    bar1 = frosteindringtiefe(subset)    
    return bar1

pn.panel(pn.Row(month,dashboard))
```

I try different methods like .servable() gridspec, but there is the same problem.

**Update**
I update the code with hard-code data. The Problem doesn't change. So it can't have to do with the xarray part because now I use a pandas DataFrame. Any Ideas? I also try

```
server = pn.panel(pn.Row(month,dashboard))
server.servable()
```

or simply

```
server
```

as well as only

```
pn.panel(pn.Row(month,dashboard)).show()
```

Every method works but does not update the plot after changing the widget.
If I change the start value in the widget month from 1 to 2 the plot is different.

Comment: Instead of relying on data in an external file that no one can see, hard-code your data into your example. Seaborn bundles several nice datasets for exactly this purpose. Be sure that the example will run by copy/pasting into a fresh text file (IOW, correct the syntax errors in this example)

Comment: @PaulH hey i'm sorry... i update the code with hard-coded data. May you can have a look :)